# Using placeholder value as default value in form?

Tags: html, forms

Is there a way to use the placeholder as value in a form, if the user dont fill in anything into it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can by using value attribute

```
<input type='text' placeholder='Name' value='Name' />
```

You question is very short and you didn't provide any other details so i might not be able to tell whats exactly you want to do with it.

Answer (score 2):

You could use some JavaScript to look at the values in the form fields prior to submitting the form and see if any values are empty, then substitute in the placeholder if needed.

Something like this (but you may need to consider a polyfill for older browsers that don't to placeholders depending on which browser set you are looking to support):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Placeholder</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="#" onsubmit="return validateForm();">
            <input type="text" name="manufacturer" id="manufacturer" placeholder="Fiat"><br>
            <input type="text" name="model" id="model" placeholder="500"><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function validateForm() {
                var manufacturer = document.getElementById('manufacturer'),
                    model = document.getElementById('model');

                if (manufacturer.value.length === 0) {
                    manufacturer.value = manufacturer.placeholder;
                }

                if (model.value.length === 0) {
                    model.value = model.placeholder;
                }

                return true;
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

This doesn't use "value" so doesn't effectively pre-populate the form with values, and lets the placeholder values render properly.